# Is there a way to call methods of a specific class randomly in ruby?

Tags: ruby, class, random, methods

I was wondering if it is possible to do something like this:

```
class Something
  def A
    puts "A"
  end
  def B
    puts "B"
  end
  def C
    puts "C"
  end
  def D
    puts "D"
  end
end

y = Something.new
x = Random.new
x.rand(y)
```

then get a random result of "Something" class

Comment: You could put the methods into a list, then just randomly pick one from the list.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A single line answer is:

```
Something.new.send(Something.instance_methods(false).shuffle.first)
```

**EXPLAINATION**

```
Something.instance_methods(false)
# Will give you [:A, :B, :C, :D]

Something.instance_methods(false).shuffle.first
# Will give you a random method out of it

Something.new.send(<method name>)
# Will call that random method and give you output
```

**FROM COMMENTS** (a great suggestion)

You can use it like:

`Something.instance_methods(false).sample` instead of `Something.instance_methods(false).shuffle.first`

Comment: Use `sample` instead of `shuffle.first`.

Comment: Also please always use `public_send` instead of `send` for public methods.

Comment: You could also work with the instance, i.e. `s = Something.new ; s.send(s.public_methods(false).sample)`

Comment: @CarySwoveland Aaa..I'm confused ! :-(

Comment: I am always amused when I read (sic), "Here's a one-liner.", followed by (get this) a single line of code. It's as though readers might think it's actually several lines of code had it read, "Here's my answer.". If the author really means, "Here's my answer, which I was clever enough to express in a single line of code", I can only say that I've read many one-liners that have been clearly inferior to a multi-line solution or just plain wrong.

Comment: Abhi, don't take my comment seriously or personally.

Comment: @CarySwoveland Ok. I thought the answer needed some improvement for readers to understand it better. Thanks ;-)

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to do this -

```
x.send(x.instance_methods(false).sample, y)
```

Now of course this won't work if the target method doesn't accept an argument.

Answer (score 0):

```
class Random
 def rand_method
  #instance_methods(false), gives methods as symbols that are only inside of Something
  Something.instance_methods(false).sample
 end
end


Random.new.rand_method # will give the random method
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.